# MacBook Air display went haywire

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

[image]

Literally out of nowhere my laptop screen went crazy. I was using it while sitting at my dining room table and stopped for probably 10 mins to look at something on my phone. When I looked back, it was like this.

- MacBook Air 13"
- Bought new 3 months ago (August 2015)
- Running OS X 10.10.2 (haven't upgraded to El Capitan because of negative reviews).
- Has not been dropped, no water damage.

Apple Care tried to help over the phone by having me reset a few things (video card, etc) but nothing worked. I have an appointment at the Genius Bar for **thursday** so I'm wondering if anyone here might have any ideas in the meantime.

It started out like this:

[image]

and got progressively worse:

[image]
[image: Screen]

There appears to be 6 vertical panels on the screen, 4 of them have the crazy colors/stripes, and the other 2 are normal. The text and mouse cursor are reversed when they're "behind" the panels.

I was able to login, see parts of my desktop, & open some items. Other than the crazy sections it seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Four days feels like a lifetime to wait for tech support.

Comment: MacBook Air does not come in 14", and there is none that are made in late 2015. Please provide what model it is by going to Apple Menu > About this Mac.

Comment: Sorry I was going from memory and posting using my iPhone. Unfortunately I can't access the Apple Menu because of the problem I'm having. It's actually a 13" - and I bought it NEW in Aug of this year so I assumed it would be the latest model. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. And have you tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC? This may be a bad graphics card, and you might need to take it into the Apple Store.

Comment: I'm not sure what those are or how to reset them. Apple Care walked me thru 2 or 3 attempts but tbh I don't remember what we were resetting. I pressed Power + Command + Option (+ Shift - I think ?) for 3 sets which did nothing and after tried Power + Command + R. Are those to reset what you said above?

Comment: Yes. Since it didn't help, it must be a graphics card issue. You'll need to take it to Apple Store to get it replaced.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what would make the graphics card go bad on a new laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Press the power button to turn on your computer.

Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
It takes a minute or so for AHT to start up and inspect your hardware configuration. 
While this is taking place, an icon appears on the screen.
When the process is complete, select US language and click the right arrow.

You can also use the up and down arrows to select a language and then press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

The AHT console appears. You can choose which sort of test or tests to perform:

- To perform all of the basic tests, click the Test button or press the <kbd>T</kbd> key or the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.
- To perform a more thorough diagnostic test, select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox under the Test button before you click the Test button.
  Note: Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.
- To exit AHT, click Restart or Shut Down at the bottom of the window.

Dropping the Mac also bends the graphics card out of place.